# How does the base URL change plain name fragment resolution with JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

An excerpt from http://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.2.4

```
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
    "definitions": {
        "A": { "$id": "#foo" },
        "B": {
            "$id": "other.json",
            "definitions": {
                "X": { "$id": "#bar" },
                "Y": { "$id": "t/inner.json" }
            }
        },
        "C": {
            "$id": "urn:uuid:ee564b8a-7a87-4125-8c96-e9f123d6766f"
        }
    }
}
```

> The schemas at the following URI-encoded JSON Pointers [RFC6901]
>   (relative to the root schema) have the following base URIs, and are
>   identifiable by any listed URI in accordance with Section 5 above:

```
...
#/definitions/B/definitions/X
        http://example.com/other.json#bar
        http://example.com/other.json#/definitions/X
        http://example.com/root.json#/definitions/B/definitions/X
...
```

Why isn't http://example.com/root.json#bar a valid base URI for #/definitions/B/definitions/X?

Comment: I notice you also posted the same question on the JSON Schema Google Group (which I approved). You are more likely to get answers by posting here, as the community activly monitors and is alerted to the `jsonschema` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://example.com/root.json#bar` would not be resolveable with the given schema.

Think of it like anchors in HTML.
`$id` is like defining a new page, so the location of `#/definitions/B` falls under "the page" `$other.json`, hence `http://example.com/other.json#bar` in the list you included that are equivilents for `#/definitions/B/definitions/X`.

If you create an HTML page which is at `http://example.com/root.json`, and try to click a link which is `#bar`, it would not find the # location because it's on the `other.json` page.

Please let me know if any of this doesn't make sense or is confusing.

Comment: I think it's confusing because $id is used to set the base URI for a set of sub-schemas, while at the same time being used for "location independent identifiers". I guess they are not so independent though, since they must remain under the same base URI, and can only be referenced in relation to the top-most base URI (in this case other.json), correct?

Comment: Location-independent identifiers work similar to HTML elements with ids. It's called location-independent because you don't need to provide a full tree based address, and can address the element directly. Location dependent or otherwise, the id is still effected by the the base URI. They are location-independent with relation to the closest base URI, not the top-most. Does that make sense? (I'm not sure I fully understood your comment, but I'm trying to cover areas I think you're trying to understand here)

Comment: Base URI <-> LII relationship is what I was after, thanks for clearing that up. Cheers. :-)